# How to pass variables from sheetJS to my html page

Tags: javascript, html, sheetjs

I am very new to everything, including this community and web programming, so please dont mind if i ask a stupid question.
I am building a little website of my own, trying to get some data from an excel file using sheetJS, then show it in a website, but nothing is showing.

Thank you very much if anyone can help me with that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js">
        

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workbook = XLSX.readFile("new.xlsx");

const worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

const mess = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

const actress_name = mess[0].name;
const v_code1 = mess[0].code1;

console.log(mess[0].code1);
console.log(actress_name);

document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML = actress_name;
document.getElementById("Code1").innerHTML = v_code1;
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li id="NAME"></li>
        <li id="Code1"></li>
        <li id="Code2"></li>
        <li id="Code3"></li>
       
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried it in a separate js file in terminal and it works. I don't quite understand. I feel it is something with the sequence of the code.

Comment: A `<script>` can either have a "src" file or it can have content in the HTML file. It cannot have both.

Comment: do you mean i need 2 script tag in the page?

Comment: Yes, you need 2. One for the script file you want to import, and one for your inline code.

Comment: i just change it like below but it stiil in error,

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
        
<script>
const XLSX = require('xlsx');.....
//"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'XLSX' has already been declared"

Comment: That means the script you are importing has already declared that symbol.

Comment: i just changed the "XLSX" variable to something else, now I have this, "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".  I tried all the URL from here ' https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#installation' but still having the issue.

Comment: Well if you're trying to do this in browser JS, you'll need `require.js` also. Honestly, if you're just getting started, you're sort-of jumping into the ocean to learn to swim. You might want to start with something less involved.

Comment: Yup it really is frustrating there's always some new errors. Thanks for the advice and help. Appreciated it.